# OpenAPI 3 -- Property is optional when written but required when read

Tags: rest, swagger, openapi

My resource has an ID (typical case).

It has also a *slug*, a human-readable but still unique identifier (to beautify the URLs, mainly).

This *slug* is *optional* when the resource is created. If the client provides one, it is being used; otherwise, the server generated one.

This *slug* is however *required* when the resource is being read.

We do want that distinction to be clear, so any tooling reading that OpenAPI specification knows what to expect exactly.

This could of course be achieved using a mix of different schemas linked with `allOf` modifiers (see example below), but I would like to avoid having to perform this composition (assuming it works with tooling in the first place).

So my question is:

**Is there a way in OpenAPI >= 3.0.2 to declare a property required-readOnly and optional-writeOnly?**

Solution using composition:

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  title: Person API
  version: 1.0.0

paths: 
  '/persons/{person-slug}':
    get:
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/PersonSlug'
      responses:
        200:
          description: Information on a person.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                allOf:
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/SlugRead'
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Person'
    post:
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/PersonSlug'
      responses:
        200:
          description: Information on a person.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                allOf:
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/SlugWrite'
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Person'

components:

  parameters:

    PersonSlug:
      name: 'person-slug'
      description: Human readable unique ID of a person.
      required: true
      in: path
      schema:
        type: string

  schemas:

    SlugRead: # required
      required:
        - slug
      properties:
        slug:
          type: string
          readOnly: true

    SlugWrite: # not required
      properties:
        slug:
          type: string

    Person:
      required:
        - first_name
        - last_name
        - birth_date
      properties:
        first_name:
          type: string
        last_name:
          type: string
        birth_date:
          type: string
          format: date
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For whomever stumbles upon this question in the future, I solved this using a base schema and derived schemas for specific operations.

```yaml
Person:
  properties:
    id:
      type: integer
      readOnly: true
    name:
      type: string
    slug:
      type: string

PersonWRITE:
  allOf: # name is required, slug is optional and id is not available
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Person'
    - required: [name]

PersonREAD:
  allOf: # everything is available and required
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Person'
    - required: [id, name, slug]
```

It is essentially the OP's solution, but moved into the components level so that you don't have to use the 'allOf' in the request/response definition.

---

EDIT:
Please note that thhe following will NOT work:

```yaml
PersonWRITE: #wrong
  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Person'
  required: [name]
```

As the documentatin states that [Any sibling elements of a $ref are ignored. This is because $ref works by replacing itself and everything on its level with the definition it is pointing at.](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/)

The key is the `allOf`, which combines all properties of the objects in the list. Upon $ref expansion, the schema looks like this (still a valid yaml, I just jsonified it a bit to point out the that the array elements are, in fact, two objects whose propetries will be combined):

```yaml
PersonWRITE:
  allOf: [
    {
      properties: {
        id:   { type: integer, readOnly: true },
        name: { type: string },
        slug: { type: string }
      }
    },
    {
      required: [name]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Last time I worked on this topic, it was impossible to provide both a `$ref` property AND add anything else to the object. OpenAPI tooling failed to load the spec when I did. Did that change since?

Comment: I have been using this technique for the past half a year (and I believe the OpenApi 3 Spec hadn't changed). The key is to use the `allOf` construct, which is made exactly for this purpose - combining schemas. You are correct that using `$ref` overrides all properties you would specify manually, but the `allOf` construct gets around this issue.

Comment: That is awesome if it works. It might have something to do with the specific parser and linter I was using back then. Maybe this one specifically did not support having both. Thanks Papooch !

Comment: AAAAAAH ! man, am I slow. I juuuust noticed that it is ALL inside of a `allOf`. Now I see what you did. Awesome!!!! Makes total sense (sorry ... a bit excited here!). I am so voting this as a solve!

Answer (score 0):

Can't see how to achieve *exactly* what you're after is possible but I think the effect may be definable by using separate fields for the desired (write only) vs assigned (read only) slug:

```
Person:
  required:
    - first_name
    - last_name
    - birth_date
    - assigned_slug
  properties:
    first_name:
      type: string
    last_name:
      type: string
    birth_date:
      type: string
      format: date
    assigned_slug:
      type: string
      readOnly: true
    desired_slug:
      type: string
      writeOnly: true
```

No idea if any tooling would do the right thing with it though!

Comment: Indeed, an option I considered. The problem is that you cannot name them the same (as in your example: we have to prefix them or chose a totally different name).